# hide elements in responsive mode in large screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, show-hide, responsive

on this page: [here](http://www.weddingpaperlove.com/bridal-shower-invitation-cards.php)

in responsive view of 360×640
I don't want the sidebar to appear or maybe appear in a click button like menu above as it is pushing the original content down
see
[image]

I have tried

```
    visibility:hidden;
```

for this screen resolution but then just the text disappears and box remains there 
see
[image]

any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: if you are using bootstrap, try adding a class like `hidden-lg` which hides the div for large width devices.If you want to hide for small devices then try `hidden-sm`.

Comment: I think hidden-sm (or hidden-xs if only xsmall devices) is necessary here. it should be added to the div currently has "products" class.

Comment: ok will try that! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.sidebar{
display:none;
}}`

according to your page

`@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.product-listy {
display:none;
}}`

Comment: awesome! so my mistake was visibility: hidden to be replaced by  
display:none;